# How to include class in symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have a php file with Paysafecard class. File is called Paysafecard.php. I'd like to include it in my controller. How can I do it?

Comment: It's PHP. You can include a file as usual. You probably shouldn't, though. Better familiarize with how  autoloading works in a composer project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Symfony surely you are using the composer autoload.

Go to the root directory path of your project and search the composer.json file.

Within it you find a directive like this :

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

This sentence indicates the mapping between the name and the directory.

Now look at the actual file path, for example `/src/lib/Paymenterio.php`

Go to the controller where you want to use the class replace the path with the autoload alias and remove the extension.

```
use App\lib\Paymenterio;
```

Comment: The file is called `Paysafecard.php` and it has pasafecard class in it. I put it in `src/Paysafecard/` directory.

In my controller I user `use App\Paysafecard\Paysafecard;` Should this work?

Comment: two things, the extension is not necessary (I edit my previous message) and the file has to have the namespace you are loading too.

That is, at the beginning of the file Paymenterio you should put: ```namespace App\Paysafecard; ``` and in the controller you must write ```use  App\Paysafecard\Paymenterio```